# Universal Link not working on iOS 9 (device)

Tags: ios9, ios-universal-links

This is the apple-app-site-association JSON:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "{team_ID}.com.domain.MyApp",
                "paths": [ "/activation/*"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have signed the apple-app-site-association file with the following command (from terminal on OS X 10.11):

```
$ cat apple-app-site-association-unsigned | openssl smime -sign -inkey /etc/pki/tls/private/{filename}.key -signer /etc/pki/tls/certs/{filename}.crt -certfile /etc/pki/tls/certs/{filename}.CA -noattr -nodetach -outform DER > apple-app-site-association
```

I have placed the signed apple-app-site-association file on the root directory of my domain and I set the htaccess in such a way that the content-type is application/pkcs7-mime:

```
$ curl -I https://www.domain.com/apple-app-site-association
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime
...
```

On Xcode (v7.2) on the project target, on "Capabilities" I enabled the "Associated Domain" and I added 2 applinks:

```
applinks:www.domain.com
applinks:domain.com
```

When I load the page (I tried directly from Safari and from a link on a e-mail) https://www.domain.com/activation/myactivationcode the page loads and there is no redirect to my app (the page itself has no redirects). I need to support my app from iOS 7, I was using custom URLs (myapp://activation?code=mycode) until iOS 9.

Is there another way to do it or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:

https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool/

I tried the App Search API Validation Tool and it says for the Universal Links: **appSiteAssociationFile** Not found

the problems is that I don't understand what did I do wrong, I tried with and without signing the apple-app-site-association and with different Content-Type: JSON, plain or pkcs7-mime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Was a load balancer problem on the server (Rackspace). From the logs, the AppleBot was getting a 404 HTTP status code.